# Passing instance values of a model to another different model instance in django

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models

I am relatively new to django and have a problem regarding passing some information from one model to another. Its not quite inheritance but rather ensuring that a parent model passes certain information upon creating a child model. So I have two models, one for Events and another for Occurrences. The Events is run via admin and when you create an event it also creates occurrences for that event. My problem is that each event is in a specific city and I would like it to pass the city value to the occurrences it creates so that I can use that city value in a filter. It should be noted, an occurrence is not an Event so this is not simply just multi-table inheritance. How do I pass on this value?

Models.py

```
# The events are models that contain the what and where.
class Event(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Events'
        verbose_name = 'Event'

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, blank = False, null = False, verbose_name = 'Creation Date')
    #Date Event was edited for the last time
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False, blank = False, null = False, verbose_name = 'Updated')
    #Name of the event
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 400, null=True, blank = False, verbose_name = 'Name')
    #Event Description
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 10000, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Description')
    #Event City
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True, blank = False, verbose_name = 'City')
    #Event Location
    location = ChainedForeignKey(
        ProfileVenue,
        chained_field="city",
        chained_model_field="city",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True,
        default=1,)
    #Price Entity
    price = models.ForeignKey(Price, null=True, blank = True,)
    #Max Number of participants
    max_participants = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank = False, verbose_name = 'Nr. Participants')
    #Event Language
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, null = True, blank = False)
    #Event Type
    event_type = models.ForeignKey(EventType, null = True, blank =False, verbose_name='Event Type')
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s:%s" % (self.name, self.location.name)


class Occurrence(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Sessions'
        verbose_name = 'Session'

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,
        auto_now_add=True, blank = False, null = False, verbose_name = 'Creation Date')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,
        auto_now_add=False, blank = False, null = False, verbose_name = 'Updated')
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    '''
    city = ChainedForeignKey(
        Event,
        chained_field="city",
        chained_model_field="city",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    '''
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(ProfileTeacher,
        null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Teacher')
    students = models.ManyToManyField(ProfileStudent,
        verbose_name = 'Students', blank=True)
    # Max number of students for this group
    max_participants = models.IntegerField(null=False,
        blank=False, default=5, verbose_name='Max Nr Participants')
    # Date and Time for this session
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,
        auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Date')
    # Duration of the class
    duration = models.DurationField(default=timedelta(), verbose_name='Duration')
    # Language Levels
    language_level = models.ForeignKey(LanguageLevel,
        null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Language Level')
    # True of teacher was assigned to class
    teacher_assigned = models.BooleanField(
        default=False, blank=True)
    # Status of the Occurrence
    # Active --> Class has been created
    # Canceled --> Canceled by human admin
    # Auto Canceled --> Canceled by the Automation System
    # Due --> Class finished. Student Evaluated. Teacher Can get Extraction.
    STATUS = (
        (1, ('ACTIVE')),
        (2, ('CANCELED')),
        (3, ('DUE')),
        (4, ('AUTO CANCELED')),
    )
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=1)
    # Evaluated by teacher: True if a teacher evaluated all students
    students_ev_by_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Alumnos evaluados')
    # If true Send Mails when occurrence canceled to all teachers that are not assigned and students
    send_cancel_mail = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Enviar Email Cancelar')
    # friendlly url
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300, verbose_name='Occurrence Url', blank=True, null=True)
```

## Event Admin Form that creates Occurences when Events are also created

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    list_filter = ['city']
    #Frequecy type for periodical events
    FREQUENCY = (
        ('NEVER', ('Nunca')),
        # ('DAILY', _('Every Day')),
        ('WEEKDAY', ('Cada Semana')),
        # ('WEEKLY', _('Every Week')),
        # ('BIWEEKLY', _('Every 2 Weeks')),
        # ('MONTHLY', _('Every Month')),
    )
    # Weekday choices
    WEEKDAYS = (
        ( 0, ('Lunes')),
        ( 1, ('Martes')),
        ( 2, ('Miercoles')),
        ( 3, ('Jueves')),
        ( 4, ('Viernes')),
        ( 5, ('Sabado')),
        ( 6, ('Domingo')),
    )
    #Date of the first Occurrence
    start_date = forms.SplitDateTimeField(
        widget = widgets.AdminSplitDateTime(),
        help_text='Date and hour of the Event.',
        required= True,
        )
    #Limit Date for last Occurrence: no hour needed
    end_date = forms.SplitDateTimeField(
        widget = widgets.AdminSplitDateTime(),
        required = False,
        help_text='Date and hour of the Event.',
        )

    #Event frequency tipe: weekly and never supported only
    freq = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=FREQUENCY,
        initial='WEEKDAY',
        label = 'Tipo Periodicidad'
        )

    #The event wwill occure on this weekday once a week until the end date
    weekday = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=WEEKDAYS,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(),
        initial=1
        )

    #Event Duration in hours: stored as timedelta in database
    duration = forms.DurationField(
        initial='01:00:00',
        )

    #Class Meta
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('name',
                  'event_type',
                  'description',
                  'city',
                  'location',
                  'language',
                  'price',
                  'max_participants',
                  'start_date',
                  'end_date',
                  'freq',
                  'weekday',
                  'duration',
                  )

    #End Date Validation:
    def clean_end_date(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['end_date'] > self.cleaned_data['start_date']:
            return self.cleaned_data['end_date']
        else:
            raise ValidationError('End-Date should be higher than Start-Date!', code='invalid')

    #End Date Validation: Occurences shall not be created when an event is updated
    #This will create too many objects and confusion.


    #Save the Validated Form
    def save(self, commit=True):
        #Getting the cleaned data
        freq = self.cleaned_data.get('freq', None)
        start_date = self.cleaned_data.get('start_date', None)
        end_date = self.cleaned_data.get('end_date', None)
        weekday = int(self.cleaned_data.get('weekday', None))
        duration = self.cleaned_data.get('duration', None)
        #Saving the Event
        self.instance.save()
        #Loading Language Levels
        levels = LanguageLevel.objects.all()
        #Calculate Max Participants for Occurrences
        #This shall be a function of the type of the event
        max_participants = 5;
        #Create Occurrences from dates(see dateutil.rrule doc's for details):
        if freq == 'NEVER':
            for level in levels:
                #Check for Future Occurrences:
                oc = Occurrence(
                    date=start_date,
                    event=self.instance,
                    duration=duration,
                    max_participants=max_participants,
                    language_level=level,
                    )
                oc.save()
        #One per week until End_Date
        elif freq == 'WEEKDAY':
            oc_dates = rrule(WEEKLY, dtstart = start_date, byweekday = weekday, until=end_date)
            for oc_date in oc_dates:
                for level in levels:
                    oc = Occurrence(
                        date=oc_date,
                        event=self.instance,
                        duration=duration,
                        max_participants=max_participants,
                        language_level=level,
                        )
                    oc.save()
        #Saving the Event
        return super(EventForm, self).save(commit=commit)
```

Comment: But why do you need to do this, when the city is always available via the Event? You can do `my_occurrence.event.city`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman because when I reference it in "occurrences = occurrencesFilter(data, None).filter(self.event.city=cityId)" for example I get the following error message: 
"SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression"  and when i change the syntaxt to "event_city" I get another error saying "Cannot resolve keyword 'event_city' into field"

Comment: But that is fully documented: use [the double-underscore syntax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships). And you wouldn't use `self` there. `...filter(event__city=cityId)`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I just realised it myself about the double-underscore. Even worse is that I have used it before and I completely spaced. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DanielRoseman who provided this answer. My issue here was that I was not using the double-underscore syntax which would enable me to access my "event" attributes. i.e `.filter(event__city=cityId)`.  Its fully document [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

You have a foreign key to an Event, with which you can access the city, for example with a property:

```
class Occurrence(models.Model):
    [...]
    @property
    def city(self):
        return self.event.city
```

No need to duplicate data in your database.

Comment: when I add ".filter(city=CityId)" to filter the occurrences it doesn't recognise the property and I get an error that goes --> "not resolve keyword 'city' into field. Choices are: created, date, deposit, duration, event, event_id, id, language_level, language_level_id, max_participants, occurrenceapplication, occurrencerating, send_cancel_mail, slug, statsoccurrence, status, students, students_ev_by_teacher, teacher, teacher_id, teacherstudentevaluation, teachertransaction, transaction, updated"

Comment: In database queries you have to use the double underscore syntax, which you already know by now ;)

Comment: yeah I realised. I am such a dunce at times. Been struggling with such a basic thing thatI know already. I think I should ditch the coffee and take a proper break!!